# dynamically add input fields with different id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, input

I've to add in my page -dynamically- a input range like this:

```
<div id="input_div">
<input type="button" value="-"  onclick="minus()">
<input name="order" type="number" min="0" max="30" size="10" range="1" value="1" id="count1">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus()">
</div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<a href="#" id="add-inputs">ADD</a>
```

And i've to add and remove numbers of that input.

For example the first input has id=count1, if I click on the "plus" button it has to increment its value. But if i had another input with `id=count2` and i click on the "plus" button it has to increment the value of the second input with `id=count2` and it shouldn't change the first input with `id=count1`.
And then I don't know how to add and remove inputs.
So two questions:

- How to add many inputs (the inputs held in the div with `id=input_div`) with different ids;
- How to do with the first question done, to increment and de-increment (with the button plus and minus) the value of the current input with its id generated automatically (different from the others)... and how to remove it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I have add the input type number... And I hope that it's what do you want..

here you are an example: [http://jsfiddle.net/ryGqZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/ryGqZ/1/)

```
$('#addScnt').click(function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
```

I don't know why you want add two buttons: "+" and "-". I obtain this with **input type number** and **safari**:
[image]

Comment: and how to do the function with plus and minus? in my input with type number?

Comment: It si forse a mobile device

Comment: I cannot see difference. This should be corrected but it is what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/Pk4eQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need create your html with java script or JQuery.
For example the following code create 10 input element in input_div container.:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            $("#input_div").append('<input  id="count' + i.toString() + '" name="order" type="number" min="0" max="30" size="10" range="1" value="1">');
        }
    });
```

Comment: There's no need to call `toString()` explicitly. JS automatically converts numbers to strings when they're concatenated.

Comment: This is not what i need, i need as written over here, to add with a click one input on times, and i need to add also the plus and minus button which increments the input with `id=count...`. Every input has to be independent from the parent. With different id and if i click its minus or plus button the CURRENT number in the input (with `name="order"`) has to increment or de-increment.

Comment: here i've tried but with no success. [link](http://www.tavernasanpietro.it/app/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need add an attribute to minus & plus inputs like as "btnId". and access to it's number with this attribute. See code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        $("#input_div").append('<input btnId="count' + i.toString() + '" type="button" value="-"  onclick="minus()">');
        $("#input_div").append('<input  id="count' + i.toString() + '" name="order" type="number" min="0" max="30" size="10" range="1" value="1">');
    }
});

function minus() {
    var btnName = $(this).attr("btnId");
    var btn = $("#" + btnName);
    ...
}
```

Comment: i've done this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pk4eQ/1/ but as you can see, it doesn't run, and plus and minus either.